# Cannot patch requests post

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I can't patch requests post method. I read http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch . But didn't understand where I made the error.

structure

```
tests.py
package
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

package/module.py

```
import requests
import mock

class Class(object):
    def send_request(self):
        ...
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
        return response
```

tests.py

```
@mock.patch('package.module.requests.post')
def some_test(request_mock):
    ...
    data = {...}
    request_mock.return_value = data
    # invoke some class which create instance of Class
    # and invokes send_request behind the scene
    request_mock.assert_called_once_with()
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 343, in some_test
    request_mock.assert_called_once_with()
  File "/home/discort/python/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 941, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
  AssertionError: Expected 'post' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

Comment: are you sure `package.module.` should be part of the string on `@mock.patch`?

Comment: no, but 'requests.post' also doesn't patch

Answer (score 1):

You are using `requests.post(...)` not

```
from requests import post
...
post()
```

So doesn't matter where to patch 'package.module.requests.post' or 'requests.post'. Both ways are ok.

```
#package.module
...
class Class(object):
    def send_request(self):
        response = requests.post('https://www.google.ru/')
        return response

#tests.test_module
...
@patch('requests.post')
def some_test(request_mock):
    obj = Class()
    res = obj.send_request()
    request_mock.assert_called_once_with('https://www.google.ru/')
```

This variant with explicit call of `send_request` is pass. Are you shure that `send_request` was called?